# Swift: get values from dynamic SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uisegmentedcontrol

i have a question regarding dynamic elements in Swift i could not find a solution for the last days.

Here's my function that creates a UISegmentedControl with different entries:

```
func createButton (items: [String], margin: Int) {
    let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    customSC.frame = CGRectMake(56, CGFloat(50 + margin), 200, 30) // X, Y, width, height
    customSC.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(customSC)
}
```

In a loop i create different SegementedControls one below the other, f.e.

```
var set1: [String] = ["item1", "item2"]
createButton(set1, margin: 50)
var set2: [String] = ["item3", "item4"]
createButton(set2, margin: 100)
```

Now my question: how i can get all values after the user has selected every SegmentedControl and pressed a button? I need something like a dynamic id or name.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global/property NSMutableArray of pointers to store a reference to the dynamically created SegementedControls:

```
var controls: [AnyObject] = NSMutableArray
```

Finally, when done merely iterate through this array to process all the values accordingly.